# Problem with JSR286 rendering portlet and WebSphere Portal7

Tags: websphere, websphere-7, websphere-portal, lotus-wcm

Another question for all WP7 lovers!

We have the following problem: we have creates a portal page with a JSR286 local rendering portlet that show a lotus wcm content.
When the portal render the JSR portlet, it show the following exception **"Error 500: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 0"**

On the IBM developerWorks, I've found this post [developerWorks Thread](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14622045&tstart=0) that tell to install the IBM 7.0.0.1 Combined Cumulative Fix 004 to solve this problem [IBM PM33952](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM33952)

Being a Combined Cumulative Fix, we've installed the Combined Cumulative Fix 007 (that containes the 004 fix)!
But after installation, the exception seems to be remained!

Have you solved this problem? What's your solution?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are most likely caused by menu or navigator components that are unable to render themselves if the resultset is zero for some reason. What you should do is to gather [WCM general information mustgather](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=688&uid=swg21315460) and reproduce the problem in traces. Then you can see what component causes the exceptions and what was the used rendering context. Inspect the context (sitearea/content) and the component. If you can't spot anything wrong with them, please submit a PMR with the traces.